# FInd Replace value of a formula in excel but incremental and loop

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2007

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
p = 3
q = p + 1
fnd = "$3"
rplc = "$" & q

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
p=q
End Sub
```

I have this formula in column A to O, and yes the cell reference is changing per column

```
='[MASTER_MASTER - Copy.xlsx]DATA 02'!$A$8
```

All I want to do is replace last two char "$8" with next value i.e "$9". Above given example code is good however I not able to run this in loop.
I would want to click on vba Run button and expecting that each click will increment the value to +1 (8 to 9 to 10) till lets say 2500.
How can I do that? Run the above code but increment the value of P by 1 at each run?

Answer (score 1):

Save "q" in a workbook cell each time you run the macro. Then read it from that cell each time you run the macro.

If the cell you save it in is on sheet "parameters" in cell A1, then this at the beginning:

```
q = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("parameters").Range("A1") + 1
```

And this at the end:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("parameters").Range("A1") = q
```

And of course you will need to make sure your existing code doesn't process the new sheet:

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  if sht.Name <> "parameters" then
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  end if
Next sht
```

You might also consider building the formula in the macro rather than using `Cells.Replace`, but that's not 100% necessary.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, that was really quick. Here is what I did, a little change to the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Little change to meet my need, thanks to you for the solution provided

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim fnd As Variant

Dim rplc As Variant

Static p As Integer

Static q As Integer

p = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master01").Range("A1") + 1

q = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master01").Range("A2") + 1

fnd = "$" & p

rplc = "$" & q

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master01").Range("A1") = p

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master01").Range("A2") = q

Next sht

End Sub
```